# spring boot sql database DML and DDL scripts

Tags: java, spring-boot

- How i could define some schema and data to be inserted into db for
  sql database in spring boot
- Also could i do this for embedded databases

For example i am using two databases and i want to populate some data or define some schema and apply to different databases before application starts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A file named import.sql in the root of the classpath is executed on startup if Hibernate creates the schema from scratch (that is, if the ddl-auto property is set to create or create-drop). This can be useful for demos and for testing if you are careful but is probably not something you want to be on the classpath in production. It is a Hibernate feature (and has nothing to do with Spring).

You can take a look in [spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-database-initialization)

Comment: just to enhance the answer - he can use schema.sql and data.sql files to manualy define the schema and to separate concerns, or to create build or platform specific scripts, as is already stated in the linked docs